# Error in converting .xls file into .csv file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I wanted to read excel file so i did following steps. First creating .csv file of the .xls file. But .csv file is opening in excel.

```
   NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
   NSString *xlsFilePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"sampleXLSFile" ofType:@"xls"];
   NSString *csvFilePathLoc =  [[xlsFilePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NewSample.csv"];
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xlsFilePath];
   NSLog(@"data value: %@", data);
   NSFileManager *csvFile = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if([csvFile createFileAtPath:csvFilePathLoc contents:data attributes:nil])
{
    NSLog(@"File created");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"File not created");
}

NSString *contentsOfCSVFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:csvFilePathLoc];
NSLog(@"contentsOfCSVFile value: %@",contentsOfCSVFile);
```

NewSample.csv file is created at application folder location. But when its not comma seperated it still opens in excel format.And when i NSLog the contentsOfCSVFile all data is encrypted. Can any body help? How to apply encoding and decoding?

Comment: Is this a serious question? Do you honestly believe you're able to convert from one file format to a completely different one simply by changing the file name? An Excel file is an Excel file regardless of what file extension you give it. If you are serious about opening Excel files then you'll need to invest in something like [LibXL](http://www.libxl.com/) but this will come at a serious cost. There is no native iOS version so you'd need to purchase the license which includes the source ($2199) and then configure & compile it yourself.

Comment: .csv file is created at that so i thought file is created. Then how to convert .xls file into .csv file??

Comment: You can use the desktop version of Excel to convert files to CSV, or you can open Excel files on the iPhone using the library I linked to above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you are doing is copying the exact content of the `xls` file to a new file with `.csv` on the end.  Changing the file extension does not convert the file format automatically.  You need to put a bit in between

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:xlsFilePath];
```

and

```
if([csvFile createFileAtPath:csvFilePathLoc contents:data attributes:nil])
```

that parses the data as an Excel file and turns it into a CSV file.  This is probably a non trivial exercise.  Best of luck.